В чем проблема с выставлением счета?
Создаю бота для приема платежей, сначала работал с тестовым api ключом, все работало отлично.
Как ввел настоящие ключи начали выдаваться такие ошибки - raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: for url: https://api.yookassa.ru/v3/payments
Вот код -
async def buy_handler(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    await callback.answer()
    payment_url, payment_id = create("200.00", callback.message.chat.id)
    inline_kb = InlineKeyboardMarkup()  
    inline_kb.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text='Перейти к оплате', url=payment_url))
    inline_kb.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text='Проверить оплату', callback_data=f'check_{payment_id}'))
    with open('img.jpg', 'rb') as photo:
        mymessage = await callback.message.answer_photo(photo=photo,caption=f'''Счёт на оплату успешно выставлен, parse_mode="HTML", reply_markup=inline_kb)</code>

Вот обработчик -
 yookassa.Configuration.account_id = Api_id
 yookassa.Configuration.secret_key = Api_key

def create(amount, chat_id):
    id_key = str(uuid.uuid4())
    payment = Payment.create({
        "amount": {
            'value': amount,
            'currency': 'RUB'
        },
        'confirmation': {
            'type': 'redirect',
            'return_url': 'https://example.com'
        },
        'capture': True,
        'metadata': {
            'chat_id': chat_id
        },
        'description': 'тестовый'
    }, id_key)

    return payment.confirmation.confirmation_url, payment.id

def check(payment_id):
    payment = yookassa.Payment.find_one(payment_id)
    if payment.status == 'succeeded':
        return payment.metadata
    else:
        return False

Полна версия ошибки -
payment_url, payment_id = create("200.00", callback.message.chat.id)
  File "c:\Users\aist\Desktop\telegram_bot\venv\youmoney.py", line 22, in create
    payment = Payment.create({
  File "C:\Users\aist\Desktop\telegram_bot\.venv\lib\site-packages\yookassa\payment.py", line 58, in create
    response = instance.client.request(HttpVerb.POST, path, None, headers, params_object)
  File "C:\Users\aist\Desktop\telegram_bot\.venv\lib\site-packages\yookassa\client.py", line 38, in request
    raw_response = self.execute(body, method, path, query_params, request_headers)
  File "C:\Users\aist\Desktop\telegram_bot\.venv\lib\site-packages\yookassa\client.py", line 59, in execute
    self.log_response(raw_response.content, self.get_response_info(raw_response), raw_response.headers)
  File "C:\Users\aist\Desktop\telegram_bot\.venv\lib\site-packages\yookassa\client.py", line 119, in get_response_info
    "raise_for_status": response.raise_for_status(),
  File "C:\Users\aist\Desktop\telegram_bot\.venv\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 1021, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error:  for url: https://api.yookassa.ru/v3/payments

В чем проблема, с тестовым ключом работало без проблем.
Библиотеки aiogram и yookassa

'return_url': 'https://example.com'
